# TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `admin` is not a valid type at path `ADMIN`, NestJs mongodb with SWC

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema, swc

**I'm first time working with `SWC` , and I'm facing this error only with `SWC` compiler. Without `SWC` everything works fine**

**Error**

> throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${val}` is not ` +
> ^
>
> TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `admin` is not a valid type at path `ADMIN`.
> Blockquote
>
> Seelist of valid schema types.

**Description**

I have a `User` schema, In which there's a property named by `role` and it's type is an `enum` named `Role`.

**enum**

```
export enum Role {
  ADMIN = 'admin',
  SALES = 'sales',
  MARKETING = 'marketing',
}
```

**Code**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { Role } from '../../../enum/role';

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true, default: null })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, default: null })
  password: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, enum: Role, default: Role.ADMIN })
  role: Role;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
export type UserDocumnet = User & Document;
```

The error goes away If I remove `Role` as a type ,like this

```
@Prop({ required: true, enum: Role, default: Role.ADMIN })
      role: string;
```

**It throws error for whatever value is present at `index 0` of the `Role enum`. For example If I move `SALES` uprward inside enum, it shows `sales` inside error**

**SWC Config**

I installed swc with

```
npm i --save-dev @swc/cli @swc/core
```

**nest-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "builder": "swc",
    "typeCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Any change if you use `default: undefined` (instead of `default: Role.ADMIN`)?

Comment: No still throws error.Even If I remove default value it still throws error.As I said If only I change the type from `Role` to someother like `string`,then it works.And Without `swc` it works fine with type `Role`

Comment: Do you have a github repo I can take a look at? Will be easier to debug.

Comment: I have do have repo but it's private,let me create a public one.

Comment: this the repo link https://github.com/m-nouman-munir/test-repo

Comment: I did `npm run build` by being on `main` branch of this dummy repo. I'm still facing the issue

Comment: It's not throwing error for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the **Solution** with the help of the answer of **@Robin Thomas**. According to his answer `@nestjs/mongoose` is not converting `enum` correctly when using `SWC`. And when we use `TSC` comnpiler, it converts the `enum` correctly. **Now it means that it's related to how `SWC` handles `enum` convertion**. So I searched and found that `SWC` can not work well with outside `enum` files. Not just that, `SWC` does not work well with `auto imports`, if you try to call one `ts file` into another `ts file`, if your imports are starting from `src/etc/etc`,

`SWC` throws error

> `CAN NOT FIND MODULE xyz`.

**SOLUTION**

I'm used to keep enum files in a seperate folder at `root of source or src`.
**But with specially `SWC` It doesn't work if the enum is imported from another file. It compiles properly when the enum is declared in the same file, though.**.

**Also you have to import files from outisde like this `../etc/ect`, and with `src/etc/etc`**.

**CHECK THIS DISCUSSION FOR ENUM PART https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/1160#issuecomment-738320066**

**CHECK THIS DISCUSSION FOR IMPORT PART https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/7603#issuecomment-1692146920**

**So I did this and it worked**

```
export enum Role {
  ADMIN = 'admin',
  SALES = 'sales',
  MARKETING = 'marketing',
}

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true, default: null })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, default: null })
  password: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, enum: Role, default: Role.ADMIN })
  role: Role;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this a bug in NestJS v10 when built using SWC. I cannot reproduce the issue when using v7 or v8 of nestjs packages (without SWC).

Regarding the issue itself, it comes from `@nestjs/mongoose` trying to create a second schema (apart from `User` entity).

The schema from the original entity takes the form:

```
{
  email: { required: true, default: null, type: [Function: String] },
  password: { required: true, default: null, type: [Function: String] },
  role: {
    required: true,
    enum: { ADMIN: 'admin', SALES: 'sales', MARKETING: 'marketing' },
    default: 'admin',
    type: { ADMIN: 'admin', SALES: 'sales', MARKETING: 'marketing' }
  }
}
```

But while processing the above schema, `@nestjs/mongoose` try to create a second schema, which takes the form:

```
{ ADMIN: 'admin', SALES: 'sales', MARKETING: 'marketing' }
```

This is not a valid mongoose schema as per https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition.

Since this is not a valid schema, and hence the error.

---

The issue pops up only while using SWC.